# SQL "WHERE date = yesterday" but date is string (yyyymmdd)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, where-clause

I'm trying to do a query in SQL that should return all records created yesterday, i know this would be really easy if the date field would be in the correct data type but in this db the date is in string.

This query returns the correct number of rows:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE createdDate = '20180814'
```

I tryed to do something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE CONVERT(date, createdDate) = dateadd(day,-1, getdate())
```

But 0 rows returned, no errors though.

Change the data type of createdDate is not an option, nor any change in the db structure.

The point is return the records created yesterday whenever the query is executed, at this point im out of ideas, please help :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the time component on `GETDATE()`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE CONVERT(date, createdDate) = DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, getdate()));
```

Alternatively:

```
WHERE createdDate >= DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, getdate())) AND
      createdDate < CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

Comment: Nice! it seems to be working perfectly, thank you very much!